# JOptionPane giving me an error when I try to use it as input

Tags: java, swing, input

I am working on a class in java that calculates the area / height etc. of a triangle , but I'm having a hard time setting the input of the coordinates through JOptionPane , here's my attempt

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Triangle 
{
private int x1;
private int y1;
private int x2;
private int y2;
private int x3;
private int y3;
private int input;

public Triangle(){
int input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter x1 for point A");
x1 = input;

}

}
```

heres's the error Triangle.java:15: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int

Comment: This is not how you use a `JOptionPane`. Please refer to [the dialogs tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

Comment: As the JavaDocs clearly state, showInputDialog returns a String

Answer (score 0):

The method, showInputDialog(String s) returns a String.  If you want to accept an int, you need to parse it.

The method Integer.parseInt(String s) should help you do this.  Here is an example:

```
String inputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter x1 for point A");
int x1 = Integer.parseInt(inputString);
```

NOTE: If the user puts in anything other than an Integer, you will get a NumberFormatException during runtime.